# Контролировать изменение переменной класса в Python

Tags: python

Имеется следующий код на Python3:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
        
    def bar(self):
        print('произошло присвоение')


a = A()
a.foo = 5
```

Можно ли как то отследить `a.foo=5`? Мне нужно сразу же после присвоения выполнить функцию bar

Comment: Выделить код, нажать Ctrl+C, воткнуть курсор в тело вопроса, нажать Ctrl+V. Сохранить.

Comment: Если нужно выполнить функцию bar сразу же после присвоения, то нужно вызвать ее сразу же после присвоения.

Comment: А код на картинке ещё и с синтаксической ошибкой

Answer (score 2):

С помощью `property`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, foo=None):
        self._foo = foo
    
    @property
    def foo(self):
        """Вызовется при запросе значения из атрибута foo"""
        return self._foo
    
    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        """Вызовется при присвоении значения атрибуту foo"""
        self._foo = value
        self.bar()  # Выполняем нужные действия после присвоения
    
    def bar(self):
        print('произошло присвоение')


a = A()
a.foo = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Используете специальный метод `__setattr__` - он срабатывает, когда вы присваиваете значение аттрибуту:

```
class A:

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.__dict__[key] = value
        if key == 'foo':
            print('Произошло присвоение')
            # Вставляйте сюда вызов вашего метода bar

a = A()
a.foo = 5
# Напечатает: Произошло присвоение
print(a.foo)
# Напечатает: 5
a.not_foo = 7
# Ничего не напечатает
print(a.not_foo)
# Напечатает: 7
```

PS: Код в вопросе нужно приводить ТОЛЬКО текстом, а не картинкой, и тем более не ссылкой на картинку.

Comment: Или использовать `setter`